# Conditional count and group by in R

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements, aggregation

I would like to count how many rows there are per `type` if they meet the condition `x == 0`. Sort of like a group by in SQL

Here is an example of the data

```
  type    x    
search    0 
NULL      0 
public    0
search    1
home      0
home      1
search    0
```

Comment: Could you include a data example with R code?  I'm struggling to understand what you're asking for and how your example fits in...

Comment: When including sample input, also include desired output. See [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to find the number of rows when a particular condition (when a variable is having some value) is met.

If this is the case, then I suppose you have "x" as a variable represented in a column. "x" can take multiple values. Suppose you want to find how many rows are there in your data when x is 0. This could be done by:

```
nrow(subset(data, x=="0")
```

'data' is the object name for your dataset in R

**EDIT:**

I am seeing your edited dataframe now. You could use this to solve your problem:

```
table(data$type, data$x)
```

Comment: i would like to count how often one variable (tasks) occurs in one month(month is a variable from 1 to 12), how would i do that?

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the sqldf package:

```
library(sqldf)
df <- data.frame(type=c('search','NULL','public','search','home','home','search'),x=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0))
sqldf("SELECT type, COUNT(*) FROM df WHERE x=0 GROUP BY type")
```

which gives the following result:

```
    type COUNT(*)
1   NULL        1
2   home        1
3 public        1
4 search        2
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% group_by(x,type) %>% tally()
```

which gives:

```
  x   type n
1 0   home 1
2 0   NULL 1
3 0 public 1
4 0 search 2
5 1   home 1
6 1 search 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the data frame,
`df=data.frame(type=c('search','NULL','public','search','home','home','search'),x=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0))`

If you want to know how many of each value in column 1 have a value in column 2 of zero then you can use:
`table(df)[,1]`

as long as you are only working with 1's and 0's to get the answer:

```
  home   NULL public search 
     1      1      1      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your data is structured as a data frame, the following code has a better running time than the answers given above:

```
nrow(data[data$x=="0"])
```

You can test your run time using:

```
ptm <- proc.time()
nrow(subset(data, x == "0"))
proc.time() - ptm

ptm <- proc.time()
nrow(data[data$x=="0"]))
proc.time() - ptm
```

In my case, the running time was about 15 times faster, with 1 million rows.